# Reading Session Value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I read a bunch of links and answers and nothing worked. So in **controller** I have this:

```
Session["MySession"] = "HelloMaybe";
```

and in the page I have this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    console.log("Before Unload Window");
    var somethingElse = '@Session["MySession"]';
    console.log(somethingElse);
};
```

I see that script is running because it prints my first log message but there is nothing in there for value of session.
How can I do this?

Comment: What is `Session` in your question? Can you please provide some code or reference for `Session`.

Comment: @shobhit1 what do you mean?  I have put a string value in there, Now I want to have access to it to read it.

Comment: Have you checked the browser's source view? Does the server insert the contents of the session variable?

Comment: I started a new MVC project, added the lines you posted and I'm getting this in the source view: `var somethingElse = 'HelloMaybe';`

Comment: @ChrisG thanks for checking ... not sure why it doesn't work for me then... hmmm

Comment: So what *do* you see in the source view? And did you make sure you're setting the session var in the correct controller?

Comment: @ChrisG : Should I go to "View Source"  right click on page ? that one ?

Comment: Yes, or just press Ctrl+U. Then look for the script.

Comment: @ChrisG this is all I have there about BeforeUnload:              portalTracker.initialize('03831ca3-72d8-48e0-b9ee-12ddef234f19', homeUrl, productName, HandleOnBeforeUnloadPortal);
            portalTracker.trackPortalSession('c4a10b23-e3fd-405e-990c-718afb069057');

            $(window).on("beforeunload", function () {
                HandleOnBeforeUnloadPortal();
            });

Comment: You said you can see in the console that your script is running, so it has to be somewhere in the source view, right? Or is it an external script?

Comment: yes sorry, because I load it modal, I should look in "view FRAME source" .. instead of View Page Source " ... ok let me check that

Comment: oh cool I see I do have it in FrameSource:           var somethingElse = 'HelloMaybe';
        console.log(somethingElse);

Comment: worked! ALL I needed to do was to add a .toString() to my code above

Answer (score 0):

```
var somethingElse='@System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["MySession"].ToString()'
```